# How to add a file other than index.js to a Firefox add-on using jpm

Tags: firefox-addon, jpm

I am building a Firefox add-on and like to include code that is used in the index.js, as well as in the worker script. Instead of copying the function, I would like to add it in a file next to the index.js if possible.

Comment: The question, of course, is: how does that work?

Comment: [This](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require) article hinted me to export my function, which finally gave me access to it. However, when used in my worker, it complained that my 'exports' variable was not defined... Can I use the same file in my worker and my central code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for addon modules you use [require("./relative/path.js")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Module_structure_of_the_SDK), for the worker you specify it through the [contentScriptFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#contentScriptFile) parameter. You will have to feature-detect whether CommonJS features (require/exports) are available.